# How to 'convert' two (for loops) to a (while loop)?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, simulation

I am simulating a fast food restaurant over three hours. The three hours are divided into 18 intervals of 600 seconds each. Each interval outputs statistics about what happened on those 600 seconds.

My original structure was like this:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<18; i++)
    interval(customerArrive);

int interval(double customerArrive)

...
...

int t;
for (t=0;t<600;t++)
```

This method of two (for loops) doesn't work because it doesn't allow time to be a continuous function. If an event happens (as in, a customer arrives) in the first interval at t=599, then this event will not exist at t=601 because everything is erased as the second interval begins.

The way I want to approach this is to make a while loop to allow time to be a continuous function, I just don't know how to 'convert' my code to this.

Would it be something like this?

```
while (t<10800)
{
...
}
```

I'm not sure what the condition needs to be for this while loop to exit.

If necessary, here is my full code: http://pastebin.com/3ec0Ks9u

Comment: Regarding the condition for when your while() loop exits, you've kind of established that (t<10800). Regarding when to fire the customer arrival, does the word [*modulus*](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html) mean anything to you?

Comment: Look up division and modulus in your reference documents.

Comment: I'm somewhat familiar of the modulus function. I've used it a few times in the program to generate random numbers. Generally, a%b is the the remainder of a/b.

Comment: We're almost there but you're going to have to use more words than "continuous function" to describe what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

"May be",i understood your problem.If you want something to be monitored (continuous function in your words),u need to take help of threads and timers,which is out of your scope for now.If you want to use something basic,the question is not well understood,please re-construct it.

Answer (score 0):

> […] everything is erased as the second interval begins.

That's not due to the two `for` loops, but instead due to the fact that the outer `for` loop calls a function, and you reinitialize stuff in that function. So move that outer `for` loop *into* the function `interval` (probably changing the method name along the way, as it no longer fits). In that method you can write

```
int i, t;
… // initialize stuff
for (i=0; i<18; i++) {
  for (t=0;t<600;t++) {
    … // do stuff
  }
}
```

Those loops won't erase anything, and you won't have to compute the values of `i` and `t` from some single counter.

> allow time to be a continuous function

Obviously, time will still be discretized in those steps. As it would in your `while` loop. If you dont want discrete time steps, you'll have to radically change your code, e.g. by computing the times when customers arrive up front, and then stepping from event to event instead of in fixed increments.